# Редирект в ModX в компоненте Office

Tags: modx, office

Добрый день! У меня к вам такой вопрос: как можно оформить правильно редирект в своих функциях класса auth.class.php? Делал по аналогии со стандартными функциями (Login в классе), там используется такой код для редиректа:

```
$this->_sendRedirect('login');
```

Который в этой функции описывается потом следующим образом:

```
if ($action == 'login' && $this->config['loginResourceId']) {
        if (in_array($this->config['loginResourceId'], $error_pages)) {
          $this->config['loginResourceId'] = $this->config['page_id'];
        }
        $url = $this->modx->makeUrl($this->config['loginResourceId'], '', '', 'full');
      }
      elseif ($action == 'logout' && $this->config['logoutResourceId']) {
        if (in_array($this->config['logoutResourceId'], $error_pages)) {
           $this->config['logoutResourceId'] = $this->config['page_id'];
        }
        $url = $this->modx->makeUrl($this->config['logoutResourceId'], '', '', 'full');
     }
```

В своей функции formRepair пытаюсь также отправить редирект, но проблема в том, что когда делаю это до возвращения Return, то форма повисает. Если после return, то просто не срабатывает редирект:

```
return $this->success("Смс отправлена на ваш телефон!");
 $this->_sendRedirect('login');
```

Так как правильно заставить свою функцию работать с редиректом? В чем секрет тут?

Хотя в той же процедуре Login редирект стоит прежде, чем возвращается значение функции:

```
$this->_sendRedirect('login');
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.sendredirect

И где вы в классе Login нашли `_sendRedirect($url);`? У вас что-то старое.
`$this->modx->sendRedirect` используют в контроллерах.

Comment: Я же вам скинул информацию из RTFM, пользуйте sendRedirect или sendForward. Даже написал, как использовать: `$this->modx->sendRedirect` или `$modx->sendRedirect`.

Comment: @binliz, Я пробовал уже использовать эту функцию, результат тот же... какой описан выше. Я же написал, что использовал ее. Ничего не меняется в корне.

Comment: Тогда надо больше информации. Виснет как? 101-102 ошибку дает или циклический редирект или какую-то из 5хх?